# Expo go instantly crashes without error message (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

**Problem:**

Hey Stackoverflow. Because of internet issues, I was testing my react native app last week only in the web emulator. Now I wanted to try it in the Expo go, mobile emulator. But as soon as I connect to the project and the js is fully built, the whole app crashes without an error message.

**What I have tried to fix it:**

I now connected my phone to my windows pc and ran this logcat command: `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V` to get the error message this way. But I can't figure out what the problem is.

The logcat command logs this when I run the app:

```
10-19 13:54:39.731  9429 11453 I ReactNativeJS: Running "main" with {"initialProps":{"exp":{}},"rootTag":1}
10-19 13:54:39.801  9429 11453 W ReactNativeJS: Constants.installationId has been deprecated in favor of generating and storing your own ID. Implement it using expo-application's androidId on Android and a storage API such as expo-secure-store on iOS and localStorage on the web. This API will be removed in SDK 44.
10-19 13:54:46.209  9429 11682 I ReactNativeJS: Running "main" with {"initialProps":{"exp":{"initialUri":"exp://192.168.1.111:19000","shell":false,"manifestString":"{\"name\":\"productivity\",\"slug\":\"productivity\",\"version\":\"1.0.0\",\"orientation\":\"portrait\",\"icon\":\".\\/assets\\/icon.png\",\"splash\":{\"image\":\".\\/assets\\/splash.png\",\"resizeMode\":\"contain\",\"backgroundColor\":\"#ffffff\",\"imageUrl\":\"http:\\/\\/192.168.1.111:19000\\/assets\\/.\\/assets\\/splash.png\"},\"updates\":{\"fallbackToCacheTimeout\":0},\"assetBundlePatterns\":[\"**\\/*\"],\"ios\":{\"supportsTablet\":true},\"android\":{\"adaptiveIcon\":{\"foregroundImage\":\".\\/assets\\/adaptive-icon.png\",\"backgroundColor\":\"#FFFFFF\",\"foregroundImageUrl\":\"http:\\/\\/192.168.1.111:19000\\/assets\\/.\\/assets\\/adaptive-icon.png\"}},\"web\":{\"favicon\":\".\\/assets\\/favicon.png\"},\"_internal\":{\"isDebug\":false,\"projectRoot\":\"D:\\\\coding\\\\apps\\\\productivity\",\"dynamicConfigPath\":null,\"staticConfigPath\":\"D:\\\\coding\\\\apps\\\\productivity\\\\app.json\",\"packageJsonPath\":\"D:\\\\coding\\\\apps\\\\productivity\\\\package.json\"},\"sdkVersion\":\"42.0.0\",\"platforms\":[\"ios\",\"android\",\"web\"],\"developer\":{\"tool\":\"expo-cli\",\"projectRoot\":\"D:\\\\coding\\\\apps\\\\productivity\"},\"packagerOpts\":{\"scheme\":null,\"hostType\":\"lan\",\"lanType\":\"ip\",\"devClient\":false,\"dev\":true,\"minify\":false,\"urlRandomness\":\"2s-g42\",\"https\":false},\"mainModuleName\":\"node_modules\\\\expo\\\\AppEntry\",\"__flipperHack\":\"React Native packager is running\",\"debuggerHost\":\"192.168.1.111:19000\",\"logUrl\":\"http:\\/\\/192.168.1.111:19000\\/logs\",\"hostUri\":\"192.168.1.111:19000\",\"bundleUrl\":\"http:\\/\\/192.168.1.111:19000\\/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false\",\"iconUrl\":\"http:\\/\\/192.168.1.111:19000\\/assets\\/.\\/assets\\/icon.png\",\"id\":\"UNVERIFIED-192.168.1.111-productivity\",\"isVerified\":true,\"primaryColor\":\"#023C69\"}"}},"rootTag":1}
```

**these are my versions if that is important:**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.9",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "async-storage": "^0.1.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.25.0",
    "expo": "^42.0.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-color-palette": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
```

I hope you can help me. Feel free to leave a comment with another logcat command that I can run too.

Answer (score 4):

In my case. I mistakenly typed "fontStyle" instead of "fontSize". It's fine in ios but in an android continuous crashes without showing any errors.

Comment: On which (type) of component was this code added to? That might make a difference.

Comment: I also had a crash I think it's when I set `{ flex: true, flexDirection: 'row' }` for styles. I removed the `{ flex: true }` and that fixed it. I think any invalid `style`s will cause expo to crash.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and it was driving me crazy. In the end this fixed it. In my project directory I ran:

npm install -g expo-cli
npx expo-cli upgrade

I got "You are currently using SDK 47.0.0. Would you like to update to the latest version, 48.0.0?" and answered yes.

After the update it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this helps, but I too have been having stability problems with Expo Go.  They range from suddenly crashing when I try to run a React Native project from Snack to not getting past the splash screen.  I earlier looked at comments of Expo Go on Google Play and found that several people have reported multiple stability issues.  While convenient to run RN through Snack online preview, I think I might need to test it via the CLI for my device.  I hope that these issues are sorted soon.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Answer is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a component used a `useState` hook after first, conditional return:

```
function Component() {

    // code

    if (condition) {
        return <LoadingScreen />
    }

    ... //code

    const [value, setValue] = useState() // this was causing an error

    return <View>
        ... // code
    </View>

}
```

When I moved the `useState` to the top of the function, before the first return, the app stopped crashing

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while, but in my case, I was using flex:'33%' as a style. From experience, if you are using CSS properties that are only supported by the web expo go seems to crash  without an error message.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was caused because I typed:

```
paddingTop: "200px"
```

instead of:

```
paddingTop: 200
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (android crashing immediately) it was a duplicate entry in the file `android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml`.

I found it by opening the `android`-Folder in android studio and running the app from there. In the `Logcat` tab I saw the following error:

```
2023-04-04 12:12:16.096 13209-13209/com.evolute E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myappname, PID: 13209
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.myappname.MainApplication package com.myappname: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to parse XML configuration from network_security_config
```

Further down in the stacktrace I noticed this line:

```
Caused by: android.security.net.config.XmlConfigSource$ParserException: 127.0.0.1 has already been specified at: Binary XML file line #11
```

removing the duplicates solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is at a loss as (still) like I was, I found that for some reason Android doesn't like some x size of images being stored on the build. In using Expo Go, there weren't any logs showing this but using adb logcat it showed there was an error about the bitmap being too large, which I think correlates to the solution I found after rebuilding my entire app file by file to eventually find the culprit.

Hope this can help someone!

Answer (score 0):

Just recently ran into this error and it turns out I was still using an old API image on the emulator.

**Open Android Studio, go to Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Android SDK. Select the latest Android version (API level) from the SDK Platforms tab.**

You can now create a new device from the Device Manager and download the latest image. Run the emulator again and it should work.