# react native expo apk just closes immediately after running

Tags: react-native, expo

after building my react native expo app i finally turned it into an apk but for some reason it just starts up and then closes immediately. i tried using it on other people's phone but to no avail. I find this very weird as when i run the code on my pc(non apk version) it works perfectly but when i build the app using expo it just does this.

i tried multiple videos such as [text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=baq_Brz8hDs),[text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kilChCwbc_E&t=171s) and [text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUS_BjOHi-c) and solutions from other stackoverflow questions like:
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72204856/how-to-build-expo-apk-using-eas-build) and [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69630789/expo-go-instantly-crashes-without-error-message-react-native).

here is my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "e870d932-a355-43d9-8631-40288d210c00"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.pablotba.robo"
    }
  }
}
```

here is my eas.json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.9.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

and finally my package.json

```
{
  "name": "robo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-navigation": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: because there's no error code, it could be coming from the code or library, you need to try to build the project starting from minimal code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, add the code and library one by one and build, see the prod is crashing or not, you need to keep trying to build and check which library or code is causing the issue. 

Check all the configuration you need to do for adding each one of the libraries, I'm suspecting react-native-gesture-handler could be the issue.

Good luck.